# Alt-Tab for Linux command line?

Tags: linux

I am wondering if such a thing exists to where I could run a Java program remotely through SSH on my [VPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server) and then <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> so that I can run other things in the command line without having to reconnect in a separate tab. I've tried looking through the Java options in the manual, but I couldn't find anything insightful.

Comment: You mean like job control?

Comment: i'm not sure what that is, but i'll give it a quick google

Comment: http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0100.php

Comment: I researched it and it woroks exactly for what I needed thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Linux/Unix kind system there is a utility called `nohup`. You can invoke any command or process using `nohup`; it will make your terminal free after execution. Linux/Unix systems also support background jobs by appending the character `&` at end of your command.

So if your Java process is as follows,

```
java <your program>
```

you can run it as follows:

```
nohup java <your program> &
```

This modified command frees your terminal and you can run another command as per your need.